# best way to redirect to another action in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a "shopping cart" and i am looking to allow the user to update quantities of an item in the cart. I have a remove link for the cart item, but the user could technically put the quantity to "0" rather than hitting the remove button. So on "update" i want to check if @cart.item.quantity == 0, and if so, then just redirect to the destroy action in the controller.

what is the cleanest solution to this? Here is what i tried but it doesn't work, and i am thinking its not the cleanest approach...

In my controller:

```
  def update
    if @cart_item.quantity == 0
      render action: :destroy
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        if @cart_item.update(cart_item_params)
          format.js#on { head :no_content }
        else
          format.json { render json: @cart_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @cart_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

`render` will not execute the action. Its probably better to just destroy the cart item in `update` itself instead of redirecting to `destroy` action

```
  def update
    if @cart_item.quantity == 0
      @cart_item.destroy
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        if @cart_item.update(cart_item_params)
          format.json { head :no_content }
        else
          format.json { render json: @cart_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

**Using Redirect:**

```
def update
    if @cart_item.quantity == 0
      redirect_to action: :destroy, id: @cart_item.id
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        if @cart_item.update(cart_item_params)
          format.js#on { head :no_content }
        else
          format.json { render json: @cart_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @card_item = CartItem.find(params[:id]) #not sure if you are doing this elsewhere
    @cart_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: will the @cart_item.destroy respond with my destroy.js or do i need to call that as well

Comment: It will not. If you want to respond with destroy.js, then redirect would be better. I will update my answer for that

Comment: that redirect does not seem to work. Should i maybe just use @cart_item.destroy and then render destroy.js after?

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is correct that render will not execute the action. Render takes the current state of your controller and then draws the view. However, if you call his function as is you will have a problem. It will destroy the item but then not render the delete view so, assuming this is an ajax call, it will not update the view correctly.

If you want to execute the controller function you have two choices:

1. redirect_to your_destroy_action_path(@cart_item) - The one thing I'm not sure of here is how well ajax works when you make an ajax call and then follow it up with a redirect. I think the action will still execute but I'm not sure if the ajax view code is handled correctly with that level of indirection. (I'd like to think it would be but have never tried coding it myself.)
2. Call the destroy function in the place where you currently have:

   render action: :destroy

   So it becomes:

```html
  def update
    if @cart_item.quantity == 0
      destroy
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        if @cart_item.update(cart_item_params)
          format.js#on { head :no_content }
        else
          format.json { render json: @cart_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @cart_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: I tried just simply using the destroy like your answer and it does destroy the item, but it does not return my destroy.js

Comment: Actually nevermind. i had the console open watching and it does not destroy the item. The quantity is set to 0 and the item still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep my controllers clean as much as possible.

If I will develop this, I will create a Jquery function that check if the quantity is zero and if yes, change the form action to DELETE instead PUT.

Comment: I thought of doing this as well, just would like to know how to do this in the controller if possible... client side checking the quantity first and then directing to destroy action based on the quantity. It might actually be the best way to do this.

Comment: 1. Add class to the button
2. Setup JQUERY onclick on that class
3. Change value of form $("form").attr("action", "newValue") if necessary